# I need help putting a php variable into an array

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

In Wordpress i have two custom post types both of which have a 'member-id' custom fields. On one of the custom post types i'd like to pull in a list of posts that have the same 'member-id'. I have this code it works when line 14 is hard coded with a member id value but i'd like to change it to be a variable value so that it will work automatically in every post. When i use the variable $strMemberID i get an error. Is there a way to safely insert that variable value? Thank you.

```
`<?php 
$strMemberID = get_field('member-id');
echo $strMemberID ;

$member_query_args = [
    'post_type' => 'member-project',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 100,
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'meta_query' => [
  [
    'key' => 'project_member_id',
    //'value' => '31589',
    'value' => '"'.$strMemberID.'"',
    'compare' => 'LIKE'
  ]
],
];


$member_query = new WP_Query($member_query_args);
    while ($member_query->have_posts()) {
        $member_query->the_post();
        echo '<br>' . the_title() . '<hr/>';
    }

?>
```

Comment: Maybe try `'value' => "{$strMemberID}",`

Answer (score 0):

instead of this

```
'value' => '"'.$strMemberID.'"'
```

try this

```
'value' => $strMemberID,
```

Comment: Great - that does fix the error :-).

Comment: But unfortunately it returns every post rather than the just ones where the member-id field is matching. any idea why that would be?

Comment: try this
'compare' => '='

Comment: Thank you Mashhood - when i try that i get 0 results returned. I'm expecting 1 a i have one where the values match. Any idea? Thanks

Comment: Jonny you've to debug this, as i can't access your DB but make sure you've "project_member_id" in postmeta table with appropriate member id, and the post you're expecting must've published status.